# Properly append to an array when handling presses

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

Within my function, through interaction from the user, I aim slowly build up an array of responses which I then pass off to an API. However, different approaches to append to the array, simply return a single position array (overwrite).

My current code as follows:

```
const contribution: Array = [];
const handlePress = () => {
  var col = {
    response,
    user: 1,
    update: update.id,
    question: q.id,
  };

  contribution = [...contribution, col];
}
```

My understanding is that `contribution = [...contribution, col]` is the correct way to add to the array.

What is the best practice approach for doing this inside a function called each time the user interacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not clear from the question, I suspect, this code is inside a component. If so, then a new `contribution` array is created on every render. You need to use useState to store this array so that a new array is not created on every render.

```
const [contribution, setContribution] = React.useState([]);
const handlePress = () => {
    var col = {
      response,
      user: 1,
      update: update.id,
      question: q.id,
    };

   setContribution([...contribution, col]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is. I thought I could get away form putting it into state as the user ultimately never sees it - my assumption for state. Working as suggested above :)